I need help in designing a genetic algorithm for matchmaking in ecommerce
I would like to implement a genetic algorithm to solve the matchmaking problem between offers and demands in a marketplace. I found a research paper which proposes the following encoding: each individual in the population is an array in which the indexes (positions) represent sellers and the values represent buyers, so that each element represents a <buyer,seller> pair. A strict requirement is that each buyer has to be associated with exactly one seller, so there cannot be duplicates. Reading the paper, it also seems to me that there is an equal number of buyers and sellers, so that each array is basically a permutation of the same numbers, like in the TSP problem (it would mean that also missing values are not permitted). The paper proposes a crossover function where two parents originate two children using a random mask to determine the elements in the parents that must be swapped in the children, and then, since duplicates could occur (but are not legal), it mentions a method of repairing the offspring (or preventing duplicates, it is not very clear to me) in order to be valid (without duplicates).
Apart from my lack of understanding of how the crossover is done, my problem is that, in my case, I have a different number of buyers and sellers, so I'm wondering if the proposed encoding would still be valid, and I'm struggling designing a crossover function, even because this is the first time I deal with genetic algorithms.
The encoding I thought of so far is the following: if sellers are fewer than buyers, so if there are less array elements than assumable values, each array will hold a subset of the whole values set, so two arrays won't necessary be permutations of each other, and duplicates are not admitted. Semantically, it means that some buyers will not be matched (their demands will remain unsatisfied). On the other hand, if buyers are fewer than sellers, so if there are more array elements than assumable values, each array will hold all the values (each exactly once) plus some special value (let's say -1) to state a lack of match for the corresponding seller. Even in this case, duplicates are not allowed exept for the special value (-1). Semantically, it means that some sellers won't be matched with any buyer (their offers will remain pending). I would like to ask if this encoding is correct and, above all, how can I design a crossover function which can guarantee there are not duplicates exept for the special value (-1). I tried understanding the Partially Mapped Crossover method, but I can't seem to make it work, and I wonder if it would  with such an encoding (where the special value can be repeated). Could you please help me in finding a suitable crossover function?
Another thing I would like to know is how I could change the encoding to allow a buyer to be matched with more sellers and viceversa: this could be helpful if, for example, a buyer is looking for a quantity of product that no seller has, but that can be obtained combining more sellers or, similarly, if there is a seller which wants to sell a quantity bigger than the one requested by any buyer, in this case more buyers could be matched with the same seller. I hope you could help me with this problem. Also, if you have a better idea for encoding the problem, I would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

What I've done in the past is to represent a candidate solution as an array of integers, but explicitly not a permutation. Let's say we normally have more buyers (Nb) than sellers (Ns). I'd encode the solution as an array of length Ns, with each value being an index into my buyers (i.e., c[2] = 5 means seller number 2 is matched with buyer number 5). If a seller is matched with no buyer, use a dummy value such as using a convention that buyers start at number 1 and buyer 0 conventionally means "no buyer" or use -1 as "no buyer", etc.
Then design bespoke crossover and mutation operators that attempt to maintain feasibility. You can look to existing permutation operators for inspiration, but they won't be appropriate to just drop in unmodified. For example, a typical mutation for permutation problems is two swap two elements. That works fine for this new encoding too, but you may also want to do a "shift" mutation that changes only one value. Pick a random seller and change the buyer (choosing a buyer who is not already assigned in that candidate solution). You might randomly choose between shift and swap when doing a mutation.
Similarly for your crossover operator -- design something that works with your encoding.
If you want to allow a buyer to match multiple sellers, just relax the restriction that you not repeat buyers in a solution and tweak your operators accordingly.

Thank you for your answer. If I design a custom crossover function that, for example, when a duplicate occurs removes it by replacing one of the twice-occurring values with a value not in the array, isn't there a risk of worsening the fitness of the offspring? It would be like taking a gene from a third parent, not necessarily fit enough.

In a GA, there's always a risk of worsening the offspring. It's a randomized search algorithm, and some moves will be worse than others. I would also encourage anyone to stop thinking of these things as trying to be maximally fidelitous to the biological process of evolution. The job is to just be a search algorithm. An infeasible solution is bad, and it isn't better by virtue of having been generated by "true" two-parent recombination. Fix infeasible solutions. Your algorithm will work better as a search algorithm.

Hello deong, hoping not to bother you too much, are you aware of a way of dealing with unfeasible chromosomes? Let me explain it better: each vector's elements represent a couple <offer,demand>; to be legal, both the offer and the demand must refer to the same product. How can I assure that each chromosome only has legit couples? I fear that simply assigning a fitness of 0 to the unfeasible couples or even to the whole chromosome wouldn't work, because legit couples could be spread among different chromosomes, while the final solution should be made up only by the fittest chromosome.

Two common options: penalize or repair. Setting fitness to zero is a penalization. Both can work, but I prefer repair. As for the how, you just write code to do it. If <offer,demand> is invalid, change one of them to make it valid. Just write code that forces it by finding a value that works. Keep doing that until the whole solution is feasible. You can try to bias the "fix" toward higher fitness or you can just make random choices among possible fixes and let selection take over from there. Don’t worry that it isn’t a pure GA. Just make solutions feasible.

Thanks. I thought that it would be simpler to partition the demands and the offers by product type and execute separate runs of the algorithm for each product. I'm having trouble thinking of a valid representation for the many to many version: to associate more demands to the same offer I could use a matrix and make sure that the sum of the quantities of the demands associated to an offer doesn't exceed the quantity of the offer. However, I can't figure how to map more offers to the same demand, even because I think that the algorithm should decide the quantities to take from each offer.
